# A fairly simple rebus

Tags: rebus

Here's a fairly simple rebus - good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not certain but I think the answer might be

> Neil deGrasse Tyson

First image

> *Kneel* sounds like Neil

Second image

> *The Grass* sounds like deGrasse

Third image

> *Titan* sort of sounds like Tyson

Comment: Nicely done!  You got it!